# When doing a scipy.signal.spectrogram, how can I tell how many time segments there will be?

Tags: python, scipy, fft, spectrogram

I have:

```
    frequencies, times, spectrogram = signal.spectrogram(
        samples, sample_rate, nperseg=nperseg, window=signal.hann(nperseg), noverlap=noverlap, mode='magnitude')
```

I have `nperseg=320` and `noverlap=80`, with a `sample_rate=16000`.

I had `232800` samples.

However, my `spectrogram.shape` is now `(161, 969)`. So that's 161 frequency bins with 969 time segments. How was that 969 calculated?

Comment: What was your number of samples?

Comment: Updated the question to include that.

Comment: Did you record for about 14.5 secs? I think the number of samples should be 969*240 (240 net samples per time bin).

Comment: Yep 232800/240 = 970.

Comment: Yup - that's right. Where did you get 240? Also, you get 970, but it's 969, so what's the reason for the difference?

Comment: You use 320 time steps per segment, but the segments are overlapped by 80, so you  are using net 240 time steps per segment. There is a fence-post problem inside of this (as in: 10 posts hold 9 fence segments), since you have n segments but only (n-1) overlaps. I'm not sure how the author treats it exactly, but you could find out either by reading the source or feeding it a sequence of finely spaced  data sets.

Comment: Can you post as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: And to be clear, does it mean that `seconds_per_segment = (nperseg - noverlap) / sample_rate`?

Comment: I'll try to research some before I'll post it as an answer.  And yes, that formula makes sense to help you label your time-axis.

Comment: @roadrunner66. I can confirm your solution gave me the right answer. So if you can post as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    time_per_segment_ms = 20
    nperseg = int(sample_rate * 0.001 * time_per_segment_ms)
    overlap = nperseg // 4

    seconds_per_segment = (nperseg - overlap) / sample_rate
    ms_per_segment = int(seconds_per_segment * 1000)
```

That about does it